# Como puedo hacer un conteo en una sola linea en Python?

Tags: python, bucles, while

Estoy haciendo algunas practicas en Python con los bucles, soy principiante en este lenguaje y nose como puedo hacer un conteo en una sola línea y que no vaya imprimiendo haciendo saltos de línea este es mi codigo:

```
n = 0
while n <= 10:
  print("Contando", n, "de 10")
  n += 1
```

Y lo que imprime es:

```
Contando 0 de 0
Contando 1 de 10 
Contando 2 de 10 
Contando 3 de 10 
Contando 4 de 10 
Contando 5 de 10 
Contando 6 de 10 
Contando 7 de 10 
Contando 8 de 10 
Contando 9 de 10 
Contando 10 de 10
```

Pero eso es lo que yo no quiero, lo que quiero es que imprima en una sola línea pero que el conteo continue.

```
Contando 1 de 10
```

Y que siga pero siempre es esa linea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los caracteres de control suelen emular las antiguas terminales de impresora donde el cambio de línea se hace en dos pasos: bajar una línea (LF=*LineFeed* `\n`) y retorno de carro (CR=*Carriage Return* `\r`).

En los terminales interactivos, el salto de línea se acompaña siempre de un retorno de carro para que la siguiente línea empieze en la columna 0. Si no quieres que salte la línea, basta con usar sólo el retorno de carro, CR, como fin de línea:

```py
import time

for n in range(10):
    print(f"Contando {n} de 10", end='\r')
    time.sleep(0.1)
else:
    print("FINAL           ")  # Borrado de línea
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar limpiando stdout cada vez que imprimas y esperando 1 segundo después de imprimir cada línea, este sería el código:

```py
import time
from os import system 

n = 0
while n <= 10:
    system('clear')
    print("Contando", n, "de 10")
    time.sleep(1)
    n += 1
```

NOTA: Si utiliza Windows debes cambiar system('clear') por system('cls')

Comment: En ese caso la mejor respuesta es la de @ChemaCortes, con el carriage return prescindes de system("clear"), saludos

Comment: Exacto ya que mantiene todo en orden, muchas gracias también por tu respuesta :D

Comment: Esta solución borra toda la pantalla; no sólo la línea contadora.